# add scrollbar to <TablixRow> aspx, .rdlc

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, rdlc

I have Tablix in .rdlc file, how add vertical scroll bar inside table?

```
<Tablix Name="Tablix2">
  <TablixBody>
    <TablixRows>
      <TablixRow> -- I want to put here scroll bar
         <Height>0.25in</Height>
         <TablixCells>
           <TablixCell>
             <CellContents>
                some content....
            </CellContents>
          </TablixCell>
         </TablixCells>
       </TablixRow>
     </TablixRows>
   </TablixBody>
 </Tablix>
```